# How to make bottom wall rounded using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am working on ball2.js. I have draggable balls inside a box with 4 walls. Balls are draggable, pullable. I want to update me bottom straight wall to a little curve so it will looks like a bowl. Any help would be highly appreciated

BALL.JS (FILE)

```
var canvas;
let xyz = 1;
var delta = [ 0, 0 ];
var stage = [ window.screenX, window.screenY, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight ];
getBrowserDimensions();

var themes = [ [ "#10222B", "#95AB63", "#BDD684", "#E2F0D6", "#F6FFE0" ],
         ]; // Here you can add/remove the theme colours.
var theme;

var worldAABB, world, iterations = 1, timeStep = 1 / 15;

var walls = [];
var wall_thickness = 200;
var wallsSetted = false;

var bodies, elements, text;

var createMode = false;
var destroyMode = false;

var isMouseDown = false;
var mouseJoint;
var mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
var gravity = { x: 0, y: 1 };

var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;

var timeOfLastTouch = 0;

init();
play();

function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    console.log(canvas);
    canvas.style.borderTopLeftRadius = "20px";
    // canvas.style[ 'backgroundColor' ] = "#000";
    // var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    // ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    document.onmousedown = onDocumentMouseDown;
    document.onmouseup = onDocumentMouseUp;
    document.onmousemove = onDocumentMouseMove;
    document.ondblclick = onDocumentDoubleClick;

    document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'touchend', onDocumentTouchEnd, false );

    window.addEventListener( 'deviceorientation', onWindowDeviceOrientation, false );

    // init box2d

    worldAABB = new b2AABB();
    worldAABB.minVertex.Set( -200, -200 );
    worldAABB.maxVertex.Set( window.innerWidth + 200, window.innerHeight + 200 );

    world = new b2World( worldAABB, new b2Vec2( 0, 0 ), true );

    setWalls();
    reset();
}


function play() {

    setInterval( loop, 1000 / 40 );
}

function reset() {

    var i;

    if ( bodies ) {

        for ( i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++ ) {

            var body = bodies[ i ]
            canvas.removeChild( body.GetUserData().element );
            world.DestroyBody( body );
            body = null;
        }
    }

    // color theme
    theme = themes[ Math.random() * themes.length >> 0 ];
    // document.body.style[ 'backgroundColor' ] = "#e2e2e2";
    

    bodies = [];
    elements = [];

    // createInstructions();

    for( i = 0; i < 50; i++ ) {

        createBall();

    }

}

//

function onDocumentMouseDown() {

    isMouseDown = true;
    return false;
}

function onDocumentMouseUp() {

    isMouseDown = false;
    return false;
}

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

    mouse.x = event.clientX + 0;
    mouse.y = event.clientY + 250;
}

function onDocumentDoubleClick() {

    reset();
}

function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

    if( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        // Faking double click for touch devices

        var now = new Date().getTime();

        if ( now - timeOfLastTouch  < 250 ) {

            reset();
            return;
        }

        timeOfLastTouch = now;

        mouse.x = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX;
        mouse.y = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY;
        isMouseDown = true;
    }
}

function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

    if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        mouse.x = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX;
        mouse.y = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY;

    }

}

function onDocumentTouchEnd( event ) {

    if ( event.touches.length == 0 ) {

        event.preventDefault();
        isMouseDown = false;

    }

}

function onWindowDeviceOrientation( event ) {

    if ( event.beta ) {

        gravity.x = Math.sin( event.gamma * Math.PI / 180 );
        gravity.y = Math.sin( ( Math.PI / 4 ) + event.beta * Math.PI / 180 );

    }

}

//

function createInstructions() {

    var size = 250;

    var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
    element.width = size;
    element.height = size;  
    element.style.position = 'absolute';
    element.style.left = -200 + 'px';
    element.style.top = -200 + 'px';
    element.style.cursor = "default";

    canvas.appendChild(element);
    elements.push( element );

    var circle = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
    circle.width = size;
    circle.height = size;

    var graphics = circle.getContext( '2d' );

    graphics.fillStyle = theme[ 3 ];
    graphics.beginPath();
    graphics.arc( size * .5, size * .5, size * .5, 0, PI2, true );
    graphics.closePath();
    graphics.fill();

    element.appendChild( circle );

    text = document.createElement( 'div' );
    text.onSelectStart = null;
    text.innerHTML = '<span style="color:' + theme[0] + ';font-size:40px;">Hello!</span><br /><br /><span style="font-size:15px;"><strong>This is how it works:</strong><br /><br />1. Drag a ball.<br />2. Double click to change colors.<br />3. Shake your browser.<br />4. Click Background.<br />5. Play!</span>';
    text.style.color = theme[1];
    text.style.position = 'absolute';
    text.style.left = '0px';
    text.style.top = '0px';
    text.style.fontFamily = 'Georgia';
    text.style.textAlign = 'center';
    element.appendChild(text);

    text.style.left = ((250 - text.clientWidth) / 2) +'px';
    text.style.top = ((250 - text.clientHeight) / 2) +'px'; 

    var b2body = new b2BodyDef();

    var circle = new b2CircleDef();
    circle.radius = size / 2;
    circle.density = 1;
    circle.friction = 0.3;
    circle.restitution = 0.3;
    b2body.AddShape(circle);
    b2body.userData = {element: element};

    b2body.position.Set( Math.random() * stage[2], Math.random() * -200 );
    b2body.linearVelocity.Set( Math.random() * 400 - 200, Math.random() * 400 - 200 );
    bodies.push( world.CreateBody(b2body) );    
}

function createBall( x, y ) {

    // console.log(xyz);
    xyz++;

    if(xyz == 1){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin1")
    }else if(xyz == 2){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin2")
    }else if(xyz == 3){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin3")
    }else if(xyz == 4){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin4")
    }else if(xyz == 5){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin5")
    }else if(xyz == 6){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin6")
    }else if(xyz == 7){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin7")
    }else if(xyz == 8){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin8")
    }else if(xyz == 9){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin9")
    }else if(xyz == 10){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin10")
    }else if(xyz == 11){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin11")
    }else if(xyz == 12){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin12")
    }else if(xyz == 13){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin13")
    }else if(xyz == 14){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin14")
    }else if(xyz == 15){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin15")
    }else if(xyz == 16){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin16")
    }else if(xyz == 17){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin17")
    }else if(xyz == 18){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin18")
    }else if(xyz == 19){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin19")
    }else if(xyz == 20){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin20")
    }else if(xyz == 21){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin21")
    }else if(xyz == 22){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin22")
    }else if(xyz == 23){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin23")
    }else if(xyz == 24){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin24")
    }else if(xyz == 25){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin25")
    }else if(xyz == 26){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin26")
    }else if(xyz == 27){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin27")
    }else if(xyz == 28){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin28")
    }else if(xyz == 29){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin29")
    }else if(xyz == 30){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin30")
    }else if(xyz == 31){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin31")
    }else if(xyz == 32){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin32")
    }else if(xyz == 33){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin33")
    }else if(xyz == 34){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin34")
    }else if(xyz == 35){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin35")
    }else if(xyz == 36){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin36")
    }else if(xyz == 37){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin37")
    }else if(xyz == 38){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin38")
    }else if(xyz == 39){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin39")
    }else if(xyz == 40){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin40")
    }else if(xyz == 41){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin41")
    }else if(xyz == 42){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin42")
    }else if(xyz == 43){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin43")
    }else if(xyz == 44){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin44")
    }else if(xyz == 45){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin45")
    }else if(xyz == 46){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin46")
    }else if(xyz == 47){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin47")
    }else if(xyz == 48){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin48")
    }else if(xyz == 49){
        var img = document.getElementById("coin49")
    }
    else{
        var img = document.getElementById("coin50")
    }

    var x = x || Math.random() * stage[2];
    var y = y || Math.random() * -200;


    var size = (Math.random() * 100 >> 0) + 20;

    var element = document.createElement("canvas");
    element.width = size;
    element.height = size;
    element.style.position = 'absolute';
    element.style.left = -200 + 'px';
    element.style.top = -200 + 'px';
    element.style.WebkitTransform = 'translateZ(0)';
    element.style.MozTransform = 'translateZ(0)';
    element.style.OTransform = 'translateZ(0)';
    element.style.msTransform = 'translateZ(0)';
    element.style.transform = 'translateZ(0)';

    var graphics = element.getContext("2d");
    var num_circles = Math.random();

    for (var i = size; i > 0; i-= (size/num_circles)) {

    
        
        
        graphics.drawImage(img,0,0, size , size);
        graphics.arc(size * .5, size * .5, i * .5, 0, PI2, true); 
        canvas.appendChild(element);
        elements.push( element );
        // graphics.arc(size, size, i, 0, PI2, true); 
        // graphics.closePath();
        // graphics.fill();
    }

    

    var b2body = new b2BodyDef();

    var circle = new b2CircleDef();
    circle.radius = size >> 1;
    circle.density = 1;
    circle.friction = 0.3;
    circle.restitution = 0.3;
    b2body.AddShape(circle);
    b2body.userData = {element: element};

    b2body.position.Set( x, y );
    b2body.linearVelocity.Set( Math.random() * 400 - 200, Math.random() * 400 - 200 );
    bodies.push( world.CreateBody(b2body) );
}

//

function loop() {

    if (getBrowserDimensions()) {

        setWalls();

    }

    delta[0] += (0 - delta[0]) * .5;
    delta[1] += (0 - delta[1]) * .5;

    world.m_gravity.x = gravity.x * 350 + delta[0];
    world.m_gravity.y = gravity.y * 350 + delta[1];

    mouseDrag();
    world.Step(timeStep, iterations);

    for (i = 0; i < bodies.length; i++) {

        var body = bodies[i];
        var element = elements[i];

        element.style.left = (body.m_position0.x - (element.width >> 1)) + 'px';
        element.style.top = (body.m_position0.y - (element.height >> 1)) + 'px';

        if (element.tagName == 'DIV') {

            var style = 'rotate(' + (body.m_rotation0 * 57.2957795) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
            text.style.WebkitTransform = style;
            text.style.MozTransform = style;
            text.style.OTransform = style;
            text.style.msTransform = style;
            text.style.transform = style;

        }

    }

}


// .. BOX2D UTILS

function createBox(world, x, y, width, height, fixed) {

    if (typeof(fixed) == 'undefined') {

        fixed = true;

    }

    var boxSd = new b2BoxDef();

    if (!fixed) {

        boxSd.density = 1.0;

    }

    boxSd.extents.Set(width, height);

    var boxBd = new b2BodyDef();
    boxBd.AddShape(boxSd);
    boxBd.position.Set(x,y);

    return world.CreateBody(boxBd);

}

function createBox2(world, x, y, width, height, fixed) {

    if (typeof(fixed) == 'undefined') {

        fixed = true;

    }

var boxSd = new b2CircleDef();

    if (!fixed) {

        boxSd.density = 1.0;

    }
boxSd.radius = 100;

    var boxBd = new b2BodyDef();
    boxBd.AddShape(boxSd);
    boxBd.position.Set(x,y);

    return world.CreateBody(boxBd);

}

function mouseDrag()
{
    // mouse press
    if (createMode) {

        createBall( mouse.x, mouse.y );

    } else if (isMouseDown && !mouseJoint) {

        var body = getBodyAtMouse();

        if (body) {

            var md = new b2MouseJointDef();
            md.body1 = world.m_groundBody;
            md.body2 = body;
            md.target.Set(mouse.x, mouse.y);
            md.maxForce = 30000 * body.m_mass;
            // md.timeStep = timeStep;
            mouseJoint = world.CreateJoint(md);
            body.WakeUp();

        } else {

            // createMode = true;

        }

    }

    // mouse release
    if (!isMouseDown) {

        createMode = false;
        destroyMode = false;

        if (mouseJoint) {

            world.DestroyJoint(mouseJoint);
            mouseJoint = null;

        }

    }

    // mouse move
    if (mouseJoint) {

        var p2 = new b2Vec2(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        mouseJoint.SetTarget(p2);
    }
}

function getBodyAtMouse() {

    // Make a small box.
    var mousePVec = new b2Vec2();
    mousePVec.Set(mouse.x, mouse.y);

    var aabb = new b2AABB();
    aabb.minVertex.Set(mouse.x - 1, mouse.y - 1);
    aabb.maxVertex.Set(mouse.x + 1, mouse.y + 1);

    // Query the world for overlapping shapes.
    var k_maxCount = 10;
    var shapes = new Array();
    var count = world.Query(aabb, shapes, k_maxCount);
    var body = null;

    for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {

        if (shapes[i].m_body.IsStatic() == false) {

            if ( shapes[i].TestPoint(mousePVec) ) {

                body = shapes[i].m_body;
                break;

            }

        }

    }

    return body;

}

function setWalls() {

    if (wallsSetted) {

        world.DestroyBody(walls[0]);
        world.DestroyBody(walls[1]);
        world.DestroyBody(walls[2]);
        world.DestroyBody(walls[3]);

        walls[0] = null; 
        walls[1] = null;
        walls[2] = null;
        walls[3] = null;
    }

    walls[0] = createBox(world, stage[2] / 2, - wall_thickness, stage[2], wall_thickness);

    // Bottom Wall Starts
    walls[1] = createBox(world, stage[2], stage[3] + wall_thickness, stage[2], wall_thickness);
    // Bottom Wall Ends
    
//  function createBox(world, x, y, width, height, fixed) {

    // Left Wall
    walls[2] = createBox(world, - wall_thickness, stage[3] / 2, wall_thickness, stage[3]);
    // Left Wall

    // Right wall
    walls[3] = createBox(world, stage[2] + wall_thickness, stage[3] / 2, wall_thickness, stage[3]); 
    // Right Wall

    wallsSetted = true;

}

// BROWSER DIMENSIONS

function getBrowserDimensions() {

    var changed = false;

    if (stage[0] != window.screenX) {

        delta[0] = (window.screenX - stage[0]) * 50;
        stage[0] = window.screenX;
        changed = true;

    }

    if (stage[1] != window.screenY) {

        delta[1] = (window.screenY - stage[1]) * 50;
        stage[1] = window.screenY;
        changed = true;

    }

    if (stage[2] != window.innerWidth) {

        stage[2] = window.innerWidth;
        changed = true;

    }

    if (stage[3] != window.innerHeight) {

        stage[3] = window.innerHeight;
        changed = true;

    }

    return changed;

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="md:block hidden">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-1.png') }}" id="coin1" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-2.png') }}" id="coin2" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-3.png') }}" id="coin3" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-4.png') }}" id="coin4" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-5.png') }}" id="coin5" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-6.png') }}" id="coin6" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-7.png') }}" id="coin7" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-8.png') }}" id="coin8" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-9.png') }}" id="coin9" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-10.png') }}" id="coin10" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-11.png') }}" id="coin11" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-12.png') }}" id="coin12" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-13.png') }}" id="coin13" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-14.png') }}" id="coin14" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-15.png') }}" id="coin15" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-16.png') }}" id="coin16" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-17.png') }}" id="coin17" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-18.png') }}" id="coin18" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-19.png') }}" id="coin19" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-20.png') }}" id="coin20" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-21.png') }}" id="coin21" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-22.png') }}" id="coin22" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-23.png') }}" id="coin23" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-24.png') }}" id="coin24" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-25.png') }}" id="coin25" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-26.png') }}" id="coin26" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-27.png') }}" id="coin27" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-28.png') }}" id="coin28" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-29.png') }}" id="coin29" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-30.png') }}" id="coin30" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-31.png') }}" id="coin31" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-32.png') }}" id="coin32" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-33.png') }}" id="coin33" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-34.png') }}" id="coin34" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-35.png') }}" id="coin35" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-36.png') }}" id="coin36" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-37.png') }}" id="coin37" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-38.png') }}" id="coin38" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-39.png') }}" id="coin39" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-40.png') }}" id="coin40" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-41.png') }}" id="coin41" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-42.png') }}" id="coin42" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-43.png') }}" id="coin43" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-44.png') }}" id="coin44" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-45.png') }}" id="coin45" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-46.png') }}" id="coin46" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-47.png') }}" id="coin47" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-48.png') }}" id="coin48" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-49.png') }}" id="coin49" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">
        <img src="{{ asset('/assets/img/coin-50.png') }}" id="coin50" style="display: none;" width="32" height="32">


        <div>
            <div id="canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have balls inside box, the box has 4 walls so ball won't go outside. It's draggable, droppable, pushable between each other. I want bottom wall a little curved so it may look like a ball in a bowl.

Comment: I am unable to get your code to run. Can you also provide the libraires you're including / using?

Comment: That is a LOT of code can you reduce that to a small sample? ... you should read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @FiddlingAway Test My Canva here : https://wooloh.com/testcanvas/

Comment: @FiddlingAway as you can see my balls are falling from top to bottom. I want to make a curve on bottom so ball will automatically come to center.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda kindly look how to make bottom of the box rounded as curve here https://wooloh.com/testcanvas/

Comment: NO I'm not going to reverse engineer all that code... the balls2.js has more than 600 lines of code, you can't expect anyone to do that here

Comment: Who is asking you to reverse engineer all that code?
There are 4 walls already created I just want to round the bottom wall not top, left and right.

Comment: provide a minimal-reproducible-example, 600+ lines of code is not ok, that much with no prior knowledge we are reverser engineering what you meant to do

Comment: What will you take to do it?

Comment: minimal-reproducible-example  under 50 lines of code will be nice...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If the problem/question is `make bottom wall rounded` there is no need to have draggable balls inside, there is a lot of code you can just remove there

Comment: The most useless answer. When the ball is not moving etc how you will see an edge

Comment: `When the ball is not moving etc how you will see an edge` ... add colors to the walls that should be 1 line of code

Answer (score 1):

Box2D doesn't support concave shapes, only convex. So you need to approximate your curve with -either-

1. external triangles mapping over a quarter slice of a donut, the inner part of the donut being the internal wall
2. The corner being a shared point on all triangles and the other two points (inside) being calculated from the curve.

-And- then make them chained shapes to avoid sticking on the edges (ghost collisions).

https://box2d.org/posts/2020/06/ghost-collisions/

However, as the balls effectively are bound outside this curve anyway because of the box preventing ball perimeter from touching a corner, you could just draw the curve graphically without needing to include in box2d as the box2d check is redundant.Although this would prevent the balls rolling if they were dropped in gravity and fell down the side i.e. specifically for dragging or pulling this would be ok.

Comment: an image showing that "triangles mapping over a quarter slice of a donut" would be nice... I thought a possibility could be using something like a linear approximation: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2020/03/11/polygons-pi-linear-approx.html instead of the bottom wall been one horizontal box, it could be multiple boxes at different angles to form the desired curve/bowl ... but with triangles I really can not picture it

Comment: Can I make a triangle using box2djs?

Comment: @ShawnMichael Yes you can make a triangle... According to the latest documentation there is a class for polygons: https://box2d.org/documentation/classb2_polygon_shape.html, you will have to check the JS port you are using make sure your verison supports it